# Convert numeric to date & time after reading date from xlsx file using openxlsx

Tags: r, date, time, numeric

I got a problem when I try to read date from an xlsx file using openxlsx. I have already tried the xlsx and xlconnect packages, but they both have something wrong with Java on my computer, so I use openxlsx.

My date data is like:

```
1/01/2015 0:30
1/01/2015 1:00
1/01/2015 1:30
1/01/2015 2:00
1/01/2015 2:30
1/01/2015 3:00
1/01/2015 3:30
1/01/2015 4:00
1/01/2015 4:30
1/01/2015 5:00
```

I use the following code to read the data:

```
a <- read.xlsx(paste0(myPath,"try/",myFileNameList[i]),startRow = 2,sheet = 1)
```

Then, I save the data as a csv file. In this csv file, the date looks like this:

```
42005.02083
42005.04167
42005.0625
42005.08333
42005.10417
42005.125
42005.14583
42005.16667
42005.1875
42005.20833
```

The class is numeric. So, these numeric should correspond to the date above. How can I convert the numeric data back to date and time?

The data sample is:

```
a <- c(42005.02083,42005.04167,42005.06250,42005.08333,42005.10417,42005.12500,42005.14583,42005.16667,42005.18750,42005.20833)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are days and fractional days since 1899-12-30:

```
as.POSIXct("1899-12-30") + as.difftime(a, units="days")
# [1] "2015-01-01 00:29:59 AEST" "2015-01-01 01:00:00 AEST" "2015-01-01 01:30:00 AEST"
# [4] "2015-01-01 01:59:59 AEST" "2015-01-01 02:30:00 AEST" "2015-01-01 03:00:00 AEST"
# [7] "2015-01-01 03:29:59 AEST" "2015-01-01 04:00:00 AEST" "2015-01-01 04:30:00 AEST"
#[10] "2015-01-01 04:59:59 AEST"
```

Gets the intended result (in your local timezone by default) except for some very small rounding error associated with the loss of accuracy when saving and reloading.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I cannot replicate your answer. I am in Melbourne. And my data involves Sydney, Melbourne and all Australia states. When I run: as.POSIXct(a,origin = "1899-12-30",tz="Australia/Brisbane") + as.difftime(a, units="days"). The result is like: [1] "2015-01-01 22:10:04 AEST" "2015-01-01 22:40:05 AEST" "2015-01-01 23:10:05 AEST" ... When I use other tzs like "Australia/Melbourne", I have the different results. Could you please explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: @FengChen - Because you didn't use the code I wrote: `as.POSIXct(a, origin = "1899-12-30")` and `as.POSIXct("1899-12-30")` are not the same thing at all.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!